# Hibernate with MS SQL stored procedure

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

curently i am using Hibernate with MS sql 2008 in my project.
I am trying to execute Stored Procedure in hibernate.
below is the SP:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserDetails] (@userId int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dcf_user_m WHERE nuserid = @userId;
END

Exec dbo.GetUserDetails @userId=14
```

Below is the hibernate code for execution.

```
Session session = transactionManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        if(!transaction.isActive()){
            session.beginTransaction();
        }

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("Exec dbo.GetUserDetails @userId=:userId").setParameter("userId", 14);         
            List result = query.list();

            for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
                com.majesco.msig.entity.UserInfo user = (com.majesco.msig.entity.UserInfo)result.get(i);
                System.out.println(user.getUsername());
            }
```

on query.list() i am getting below error.

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/msig] is completed
Hibernate: Exec dbo.GetUserDetails @userId=?
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:592)
```

how to resolve this issue, kindly help. Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Another guess :-), try to add the entity information

```
   Query query = session
     .createSQLQuery("Exec dbo.GetUserDetails @userId=:userId")
     .addEntity(UserInfo.class)
     .setParameter("userId", 14);
```

Taken [from here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/).

Comment: I have another proposal, still guessing I'm afraid.